# How can I make the outputs in one line without making them in one print order

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How can I make the outputs in one line without making them in one print order.

[image]

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here

        System.out.println("body");
        System.out.println("hoda");


    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.print() instead of System.out.println()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Difference between System.out.println() and System.out.print()**

The only difference between println() and print() method is that println() throws the cursor to the next line after printing the desired result whereas print() method keeps the cursor on the same line.

**Example -**

`print()` method.

```
System.out.print("body ");
System.out.print("hoda");
```

The output for these statements will be-

```
body hoda
```

`println()` method.

```
System.out.println("body ");
System.out.println("hoda");
```

The output for these statements will be-

```
body
hoda
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.out.print`
(instead of `System.out.println`)